# Replace bold text from textview?

Tags: java, android, string, replace, bold

Is there any way to carry over the bold text from my array into my third textview? I've already carried it over from the XML to my first and second textviews by performing a button click for each. I'm trying to have my third textview replace the bold words in the sentences with the bold animals. My third textview will be constantly displaying the new combinations every second so that each time a button is clicked to change either the animal OR the sentence, the textview will show the new combo.

This is my strings.xml

```
<string-array name="Sentences">
        <item>"The big <![CDATA[<b>This</b>]]> ate the worm"</item>
        <item>"The <![CDATA[<b>Is</b>]]> is strong"</item>
        <item>"Every <![CDATA[<b>Just</b>]]> can run"</item>
        <item>"I saw a <![CDATA[<b>A</b>]]>"</item>
        <item>"The <![CDATA[<b>Test</b>]]> was sleeping"</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Animals">
        <item>"<![CDATA[<b>Cow</b>]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[<b>Sheep</b>]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[<b>Dog</b>]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[<b>Pig</b>]]>"</item>
        <item>"<![CDATA[<b>Chicken</b>]]>"</item>
    </string-array>
```

this is my main.java

```
package com.MyFirstApp.App1;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;



public class Original extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_sentence = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sentence );
        Button btn_animal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_animal );

        final Random ran = new Random();
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sentencetext);
        final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.animaltext);
        final TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newsentencetext);


        btn_sentence .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] NewText = null;
                NewText = res.getStringArray(R.array.Sentences);
                String strRandom = NewText[ran.nextInt(NewText.length)];
                text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(strRandom));
            }
            });
        btn_animal .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] NewText2 = null;
                NewText2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Animals);
                String strRandom2 = NewText2[ran.nextInt(NewText2.length)];
                text2.setText(Html.fromHtml(strRandom2));
            }
            });

        Thread t = new Thread() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                try {
                  while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {



                          String str = Html.fromHtml(text1).toString();
                          String str2 = text2.getText().toString();
                          str = str.replaceAll("<![CDATA[<b></b>]]>", str2);
                          text3.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));

                      }
                    });
                  }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
              }
            };

            t.start();}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

This is where I'm having my problem

```
 String str = Html.fromHtml(text1).toString();
 String str2 = text2.getText().toString();
 str = str.replaceAll("<![CDATA[<b></b>]]>", str2);
 text3.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

I can't seem to get the bold text from the first textview or the second textview. 
For instance

```
`String str2 = text2.getText().toString();`
```

only returns the text in the second textview, but it isn't bold like i need it to be. After I fix this, I'm hoping I can use this line

```
str = str.replaceAll("<![CDATA[<b></b>]]>", str2);
```

to replace the old bold text with the new bold animal.

Help would be much appreciated

```
 ~TylerNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this to build bold mixed charsequesnce

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    SpannableStringBuilder b = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    b.append("hello ");
    String boldData = "bold Data";
    int startix = b.length();
    int len = boldData.length();
    b.append(boldData);
    b.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startix, startix + len, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(b);
```

Comment: The only problem is that I can't just append bold text, I'd have to replace the bold text from my first textview with the bold text from my second textview and display it in my third textview

Comment: If i could do a code like this...

String str2 = text2.getText(fromHtml).toString();

it might work